# Choose custom zsh-prompt based on which emulator I use

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal, theme, terminal-emulator

I use powerlevel9k-theme to get a fancy zsh-prompt. But the fonts and glyphs I use to get my desired prompt, are not compatibel with the the terminal emulator I use to ssh into my workstation (JuiceSSH on Android).

I tried to let my `.zshrc` "detect" which emulator is in use. On my workstation I use gnome-terminal. So I wrote a simple function to check for the existence of a gnome-specific variable `$VTE_VERSION`:

```
## functions.zsh: Choose theme based on emulator
function choosetheme() {
 if [ -n "${VTE_VERSION+1}" ]
 then
     zgen load bhilburn/powerlevel9k powerlevel9k ## fancy theme
 else
     zgen oh-my-zsh themes/avit ## basic theme for Android use
 fi
}
```

And then in my `.zshrc`:

```
source functions.zsh
choosetheme
```

But the result is that powerlevel9k prompt is shown regardless which emulator.

Any ideas how to accomplish this task of having different prompts/themes on different emulators? Or maybe I have overlooked something?

Comment: Does 'choosetheme` work if you run it interactivly?

Comment: What's the `+1` after `${VTE_VERSION` for?

Comment: _@icarus_ Same result when run interactively. The powerlevel9k prompt is always shown. _@thrig_ I'm actually not quite sure what `+1` does.

Comment: When I test the function by means of this: `if [ -n "${VTE_VERSION+1}" ]; then echo Fancy theme; else echo Basic theme; fi`, it correctly prints the echo based on which emulator I use. I think I have to have a closer look at powerlevel9k in combination with zgen framework. I suspect it's not an ordinary theme which can be changed interactively.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
ps -p$PPID | awk '{print $4}'
```

will return two lines, with the second line being exactly whichever terminal emulator  you are using.
Hope I helped =)